# How to download my own extension's project files?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I want to make some updates on a Google Chrome Extension. 
It's **my own** extension, not a foreign one. I have access to developers page but couldn't find out how to download my last uploaded .zip file, i.e. my last version.

I ask for this because I don't have the files on my computer already. So, how can I download the .zip which I uploaded last time?

### Solution

1. Get extension ID. It's something like `bfbmjmiodbnnpllbbbfblcplfjjepjdn`.
2. Replace the `~~~~` with the extension ID on this link:
   https://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx?response=redirect&x=id%3D~~~~%26uc
3. Paste the link with the replaced ID into another browser (***not Chrome***) and it will prompt a `save dialog`. Save the `.crx` file.
4. Rename the `.crx` file to `.zip` file and extract the archive.

**Note:** When I tried to open the `.zip` it seems broken and I got an error, but when I extract it directly everything is OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change the extension to `.zip` and open it with your favorite zip application, as this is in fact a package.

Comment: But where to change? I can't see a download link. If I download with `Save As` too many files are downloaded and non of them are mine. I remind that I don't have the files on my computer and I have to download them from the webstore somehow.

Comment: @enenen See this discussion: [Download an Extension (.crx file) WITHOUT installing it?](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/g02KlhK12fU), I am sure it will help you getting the `.crx` file.

Comment: Thanks! It worked with downloading the `.crx` using another browser.

Answer (score 1):

If you using windows operating system.

1. Add your extention from chrome.
2. `C:\Users\%userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\bfbmjmiodbnnpllbbbfblcplfjjepjdn` paste and enter this path in your windows file explorer

You can get your extenstion files.

Comment: nice and simple, only change url to %userprofile%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Extensions\bfbmjmiodbnnpllbbbfblcplfjjepjdn